# date parsing exception

Tags: jodatime

I am setting a date in my xml using joda. I am using poi to get the date from a excelsheet and setting it in the xml using the following code:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss zzz")
                  .withLocale(Locale.getDefault());
                   DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(summaryObj.getCreateDateTime().toString());

                   DateTimeFormatter fmt1 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
                   //get current date only
                   DateTime currentDate = new DateTime();
                   int day = currentDate.getDayOfMonth();
                   int month = currentDate.getMonthOfYear();
                   int year = currentDate.getYear();
                   DateTime dt1 = fmt1.parseDateTime(String.valueOf(day)+"/"+ String.valueOf(month)+"/"+String.valueOf(year));
                listOfPossibleEntities.add("DateOfCreation");
                gc.setTime(dt1.toDate());
                globalContextObj.setDateOfCreation(DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
                        .newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc));
```

The summaryObj.getCreateDateTime().toString() produces a string like "Sat Sep 16 05:30:00 IST 2006". I am getting an exception for the function parseDateTime().

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Sat Sep 16 05:30:00 IST 2006" is malformed at " Sep 16 05:30:00 IST 2006"
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:866)
at scanning.ScanningEngine.getGlobalContext(ScanningEngine.java:2633)
```

I was initially using date directly instead of joda but we ran into an exception for jackson deserialiser while returning the xml as a json using REST. This is the reason I decided to switch to joda as I saw some posts saying that there is some bug in jackson for java.util.Date deserialisations.

If anyone has any idea why the invalidformat exception is coming please let me know. 
Thanks.

Comment: Isn't an extra comma here `DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss zzz")`? If you remove the comma should work.

Comment: no change same exception

Answer (score 0):

If `summaryObj.getCreateDateTime().toString()` is `Sat Sep 16 05:30:00 IST 2006` parseDateTime will throw an exception with your formatter. 'z' cannot be parsed (source: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html), so you have to change `IST` to `+0530`. Then, modify the formatter, trying with `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z YYYY")`. The formatter have to resemble the feeding string. I wrote this code based on your example and it works.

```
String summaryObj = "Sat Sep 16 05:30:00 +0530 2006";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z YYYY")
  .withLocale(Locale.getDefault());
DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(summaryObj);
```

**EDIT** based on kavita's comment, I think the problem with the formatter needs a better explanation. 
You were using this formatter `EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss zzz`, but your input string looks like `Sat Sep 16 05:30:00 IST 2006`, so

- `Sat` is patterned by `EEE`, which is correct
- the comma is not in the string, that's why I asked you to remove it
- `Sep` is trying to be patterned by `dd`, which is the pattern for days, and here is the answer to kavita's comment (why here and not on `IST`). The pattern for `Sep` must be `MMM`
- `16` represents days, so the pattern is `dd`
- `05:30:00` represents hours:minutes:seconds and the pattern is `HH:mm:ss`
- `IST` is the timezone abbreviation, and the pattern is0 `z` (please note, a single `z`, not 3 like in the original pattern). Unfortunately, it cannot be parsed
- `2006` represents years and the pattern `YYYY` is correct

As for the other question (how can I change the `toString` of a `Date`) I don't know if it is possible, I suggest to use [SimpleDateFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) like

```
DateFormatter formatter = new SimpleDateFormatter("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z YYYY");
String date = formatter.format(summaryObj.getCreateDateTime());
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z YYYY")
    .withLocale(Locale.getDefault());
DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(date);
```

Comment: IST is not hardcoded! I am just writing the java.util.Date object to string. How can I change it?? Also shouldn't the error show the problem as IST rather than Sat

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using `new DateTime(summaryObj.getCreateDateTime());`
This does not give me any exception for IST or otherwise.